# ArcGIS JS - Use square extent of a polygon to create a square polygon?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I have a polygon that is dynamically created at the end of a sub-routine in my JS. I know I can get the xmin, xmax, etc out of this but I am not sure how to create a square polygon and what attributes to pull this extent info from. I tried the following one-liner:

```
map.graphics.add(new Graphic(unionPoly.getExtent(), symbol));
```

where unionPoly is the polygon I am trying to create the square polygon from. I do not get any errors and the "symbol" variable is used by another polygon that is being drawn clearly, using that defined symbology.

Answer (score -1):

N/M, this did in fact work! Line of code was placed in the wrong area.